# How do I configure PHP + Apache on Amazon EC2?

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

I am new to this of course.

I am trying to configure PHP and Apache on a new Amazon EC2 AMI. This is a very lightweight server so the Micro instance fits the bill.

I just need
Apache
PHP

I ran

```
 sudo yum install apache2
 sudo yum install php
```

I copied `info.php` to `/var/www/html`

info.php only contains

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

when i browse to http://www.example.com/info.php Apache serves info.php but it does not render it. I looks like apache is not configured to handle php files. What step or steps am I missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First try using full tags, so your script would be.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

instead of `<? ?>`

If no luck, try:

```
sudo yum remove php
sudo yum install php
```

then `service httpd restart`

Alternatively try using one of the pre-built AMI's. Community AMI's have several LAMP configurations.

Comment: Using '<?php phpinfo(); ?>' instead of '<? phpinfo(); ?>
' fixed it. Thanks!!

Comment: I had no luck. Thanks.

Comment: On AWS, installed Apache on Amazon Linux 2,  then installed PHP.  But PHP didn't work -- just displayed code. 
 Executing this made php work for me:  sudo service httpd restart

Answer (score 5):

Just for those who get here from Google, try this:

```
sudo yum install -y php
sudo yum -y install httpd
```

If you need development versions:

```
sudo yum install -y php-devel
sudo yum -y install httpd
```

If you need Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.4:

```
sudo yum install -y php54
sudo yum -y install httpd24
```

From:
[Install Apache, PHP, and MySQL on Amazon Linux](http://codingsteps.com/install-apache-php-apc-mysql-on-amazon-ec2-with-amazon-linux-ami/)
[Install Apache 2.4, PHP 5.4, and MySQL on Amazon Linux](http://codingsteps.com/install-apache-2-4-php-5-4-php-apc-on-amazon-ec2-with-amazon-linux/)

Comment: Links have expired

Answer (score -14):

Just tar your info.php;

Upload it to another public directory;

Get the file to ec2 with wget;

Untar the file.

That's it ;)